# The app crash when I control if box is checked

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I learning Android and i'm testing the buttons.
Now i'm testing RadioButton, and I want to control if the button is cheked or not, i know that the correct stament is "rb.isChecked()", but when i use it, my app crash.

This is the code:

```
RadioButton rb;
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPPlat);
rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
if(rb.isChecked())
{
    tv.setText("20EUR");
}
```

Comment: Try rb.isChecked() == true

Comment: What is the Exception thrown?  You can see it in logcat.  It could be crashing anywhere in your app, not just these few lines of code.

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: The problem is because rb is a RadioButton of other activity.

Answer (score 0):

'`rb.isChecked()`' is a Boolean, so there is no need to do'`rb.isChecked() == true`', this is a bad practice and should be avoided.
If following is not working,

```
   if RadioButton rb;
    rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    if(rb.isChecked())
    {
        tv.setText("20EUR");
    }
```

then verify the `xml` in the `R.id.radioButton` is wrong referenced.